# How to serialize an array into json object?

Tags: python, arrays, json, serialization

I am writing a web scraper that gets a `car_id` and all of its images:

```py
car_id = 12345
images = []
image_list = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.carousel-inner a img')
for img in image_list:
    img_url = img.get_attribute('src')
    if img_url:
        images.append(img_url)
```

The output of the program is a json object, containing car_id and a list of its images... but how do I serialize the python array into the following json object?

```py
item = {
    'car_id': car_id,
    'images': ["img1", "img2", ...] # serialize images array 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
car_id = 12345
images = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'] #list of image urls

item = {
    'car_id' : car_id,
    'images' : images
}
```

The `item` dict can be edited using

```
item['images'].append('url4')
```

If instead the images list has actual image objects (serialized into bytes or some other format), then the `images` list can contain those objects.

The variable `item` will be of type `dict` in python. This may be sufficient for your use case. If not then you may want to convert it to [json string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

```
import json
result = json.dumps(item)
```

`result` will have the required json string.

Answer (score 1):

initialize the item then use `item['images'].append(img_url)`

```
items = []

for id in listID:
    item = {
      "car_id": id, # 12345
      "images" = []
    }
    
    image_list = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.carousel-inner a img')
    for img in image_list:
        img_url = img.get_attribute('src')
        if img_url:
            item['images'].append(img_url)
            
    items.append(item)
    
print(items)

'''
[{
    'car_id': 12,
    'images': ["img1", "img2", ...] 
},
{
    'car_id': 23,
    'images': ["img1", "img2", ...]
}]
'''
```